# How to use a function of another class in the current class

Tags: php, oop

I have a class called `adminItems` within `adminitems.class.php`. I am trying to include one of the function of this class in `xmlParser::someName()` within `xmlParser.class.php`.

Like this:

```php
require_once("adminitems.class.php");
$obj = new adminitems();

class xmlParser
{
    function someName()
    {
        $obj->addAds(); // addAds is within adminItems object
    }
}
`
```

Is this a correct way of doing it?

Comment: "Dependency Injection"

Comment: You'll require object of `class1` suppose `A` then in `classB` use it as `$b=new A(); $b->MethodFromClassA();`, Or use inheritance.

Comment: Please stop adding ".class" suffix. What will you do when you need to autoload an interface? Oh, yeah, btw. Learn how do do autoloading

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Don't use **extends** simply to gain extra functionality. This is a code smell and implies that `xmlParser` **is-a** `adminItems` which it is obviously not. Also, you can't then extend again in the future because PHP doesn't have multiple inheritance. Choose [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) like this example shows.

Use **Dependency Injection**. Invert the control of your objects so that they *don't depend on each other*: see [Inversion on Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

```php
class xmlParser
{
    /**
     * @var adminItems
     */
    protected $adminItems;

    /**
     * @constructor
     * 
     * @param adminItems $adminItems
     */
    public function __construct(adminItems $adminItems)
    {
        $this->adminItems = $adminItems;
    }

    /**
     * Whatever this does...
     */
    function someName()
    {
        $this->adminItems->addAds();
    }
}
`
```

You need to, *external to the classes you create*, wire them together like so. You pass `adminItems` *into* the `xmlParser`, then use it how you need to. This is called [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and is something you can do in all object oriented languages, not just php.

You would use the above object API like this:

```
$adminItems = new adminItems;
$xmlParser  = new xmlParser($adminItems);
$xmlParser->somName();
```

Really simple. Your objects (think of them as re-usable libraries) should not depend on other objects except by constructor or method injection - so you can substitute them out leading to testable and inherently clean code.

Also, I urge you to take a look at the following useful links:

- [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for naming conventions:

  - Use `XmlParser` instead of `xmlParser` for your class names
- [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for autoloading:

  - Learn how to use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to generate your autoload files for you
  - Learn how your files have a 1:1 mapping with directory structure
  - Learn how you only ever need to use an include **once** in your project

Comment: You could add the PSR-4 as it apparently superceeded PSR-0. It's a nice answer anyway.

Comment: @Rangad Agreed, I'll do this now.

Comment: @jimbo thank you for the answer very descriptive . I will try to write the classes this way from now onwards .

Answer (score 2):

If a class `B` need a function of the class `A`, you have many solutions in PHP:

**1. Inheritance**

Extend the class `A` with the class `B`. The class `B` will be able to access the public and protected method of the class `A`.

```
class B extends A {
}
```

I wouldn't recommend this. It is a really bad practice in OOP to use inheritance just to use one function of a class that has not the same responsability.

**2. Traits**

Use [traits](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.oop5.traits.php) (since PHP5.4.0):

```
trait factoredMethods {
    function getX() { /*...*/ }
    function setY() { /*...*/ }
}

class A {
    use factoredMethods;
}

class B {
    use factoredMethods;
}
```

This could be an interesting solution in certain cases but it is often a patch on a bad conception.

**3. Composition**

The best option is to use composition. `B` uses `A`:

```
class A {
}

class B {
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a) {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);
```

Of course, the method you want to use in `A` must be public. I would highly suggest to use an interface between `A` and `B` in order to have a low coupling.

Comment: I would move Composition to the top. It should be the "default solution".

Comment: I would avoid traits - especially as a sort of "multiple inheritance" solution - they're basically static access: [interesting reading](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/04/12/traits_are_static_access.html). Particularly user comments too (they go a little deeper).

Comment: @ThW If you see the best solution in first what is the point of reading the other solutions (and know why they are bad)?

Comment: @Gnucki Your answer is still useful :-)

Comment: @Jimbo I agree 100%, traits are often used to do a multiple inheritance. This is a bad OOP practice because a class shouldn't handle more than one responsability and inheritance should only be used to factorize code for classes of same responsability. Nice link.

Comment: Because the default solution does not fit all. Standard/best solution first, special cases below (as further information).

Answer (score -5):

Almost the correct method - but $obj is not in scope. An ugly solution would be to delcare it in the global scope...

```
require_once("adminitems.class.php");
global $obj;
$obj = new adminitems();

class xmlParser
{

function someName()
{
   global $obj;
   $obj->addAds();

}
```

You can refine this approach using namespaces but the right answer is probably to pass a reference into scope, e.g.

```
function someName($obj)
{
   $obj->addAds();

}
```

Comment: Some very partisan voting going on here. 4 downvotes and only one comment (now deleted)?

Comment: Most of SO will consider the `global` keyword evil. And in cases where another solution is clearly cleaner the downvotes are likely justified, I think.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer, the problem is that some users are imposing their way of solving things, I mean, when did global variables become evil.

Comment: (I think I said it was ugly) Namepsaces create an orthogonal scope mechanism - and whether that is a viable approach to addressing the problem of scope pollution (the reason why "Most of SO will consider the global keyword evil") would be an interesting argument - but not one I am proposing here. The OPs problem seems to be that they didn't understand scope at all.

Answer (score -5):

You can use other class function by extending the parent class

```
class xmlParser extends adminitems{ 
    function someName(){ 
       $obj->addAds(); 
 } 
}
```